# $sum operation on array of objects of different types in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I have the below schema as the MongoDB document:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "sections": [
    {
      "order": 1,
      "categoryData": {
        "department": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "english"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "order": 2,
      "categoryData": {
        "location": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "US"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "order": 3,
      "categoryData": {
        "salary": {
          "amount": 240000,
          "currency": "$"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

No I want to group the above documents by "department" and "location" , after which sum up the salary part.

I have done the below steps:

1. $unwind "section"
2. $group - id(location, department) and totalSalary:
   sum(section.categoryData.salary.amount)
   The problem is unwinding will separate the section array and the group will create two results one in which location and department are present and another where it is absent, totalSalary is 0 in one and sum in the other as expected. Not sure how to handle this. I am new to mongoDB sorry if I am not able to explain clearly.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this match with your requirement

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": { //copy field sections 
      "tmpSections": "$sections"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$tmpSections" //Deconstructs section copy
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "departmen": { // if the deparment have multiple keys, change $first => $push 
        "$first": "$tmpSections.categoryData.department"
      },
      "location": { // if the location have multiple keys, change $first => $push 
        "$first": "$sections.categoryData.location"
      },
      "totalSalary": {
        "$sum": "$tmpSections.categoryData.salary.amount" // sum total per _id
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MONGO PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MewWzpVgTT1)